# Erro ao ocultar campo com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video

Tenho um código em html e gostaria de ocultar um campo quando selecionar a opção "Gráfico" (quando o campo estiver visível preciso que ele esteja configurado "***required autofocus***") e tentei com jquery, porém, sem sucesso.

HTML

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">TIPO:
<div class="input-group col-lg-10">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</div>
<select required autofocus name='tipo_r' id='tipo_r' class="form-control">
<option value="LISTA">LISTA</option>
<option value="GRAFICO">GRÁFICO</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>  

<div id="ocultar" class="col-sm-3">OPERADORA:
<div class="input-group col-lg-10">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</div>
<select class="form-control" id="op" name="op">
<option value="">SELECIONAR</option>
<option value="OP1">OP1</option>
<option value="OP2">OP2</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tipo_r").change(function(){
var valor = $('#op');
if( $(this).val() == "GRAFICO")
valor
.show()
.attr('required', true)
.focus();
else
valor
.hide()
.attr('required', false);        
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro o seu campo que tem que estar oculto já deve começar oculto, para isso coloque `display:none` nele no CSS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se não quiser usar CSS basta colocar `var valor = $('#op');
  valor.hide();` antes da função `change()`, para ele começar oculto

```js
var div = $('#ocultar');
div.hide();

$(document).ready(function() {
  var valor = $('#op');
  valor.hide();
  $("#tipo_r").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "GRAFICO") {
      valor.show().attr('required', true).focus();
      div.show()
    } else {
      valor.hide().attr('required', false);
      div.hide()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <div class="col-sm-3">TIPO:
    <div class="input-group col-lg-10">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </div>
      <select required autofocus name='tipo_r' id='tipo_r' class="form-control">
        <option value="LISTA">LISTA</option>
        <option value="GRAFICO">GRÁFICO</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="ocultar" class="col-sm-3">OPERADORA:
    <div class="input-group col-lg-10">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control" id="op" name="op">
        <option value="">SELECIONAR</option>
        <option value="OP1">OP1</option>
        <option value="OP2">OP2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, mas, tem como ele já está visível e depois ficar oculto?

Comment: @Carlos fiz uma edição na resposta, olha o JS agora como ficou, o hide do select tem que ser feito antes do change()

Comment: Excelente deu mto certo.

Comment: Tenho uma duvida. Como posso ocultar uma <div> junto com esse campo? Na realidade esse campo vem junto de uma div. Eu vou editar meu código.

Comment: O que gostaria de fazer era ocultar todo elemento compreendido pela <div> e ao estar visível o <select> está configurado com required autofocus.

Comment: @Carlos eu vi que vc editou, mas qual div vc quer ocultar? É só colocar um ID na div e colocar antes do .change assim `$("#ID-da-sua-div").hide()` ou vc coloca o ID que estava no select oculto na div que vc quiser...

Comment: @Carlos se vc  não conseguir com a dica acima me fala  que edito a resposta

Comment: Pronto eu editei a id é id="ocultar". Como eu sou novo no javascript não tenho muita noção de como fazer. Mto obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Carlos tá lá da uma olhada  inclui  o HTML novo na resposta e ajustei o código colocando `var div = $('#ocultar');
  div.hide();` e incluindo o show e hide  tb dentro da função .change() se a sua intenção é mesmo aprender esse simples código pode te ajudar em um monte de coisa, e olhando ele com calma não é difícil  de entender o que foi feito... E se vc reparar nem precisa mais esconder e mostra o Select já que ele está dentro da Div ;), se quiser pode remover essa parte do código

Comment: Mto obrigado pela paciência e pela ajuda. Aprendi muito com vc. Deu tudo certo. Valeu.

Comment: @Carlos guarde o código pode te ajudar no futuro rss, mas principalmente, estude JS puro e esquece jQuery...